# Custom category link for each category

Tags: wordpress, seo, hyperlink

In each blogpost, beneath the title I also display the links to the categories in which the blog posts appear. These links have the standard /category/ syntax.

For SEO purposes I've also set up some landing pages which list all the blog posts in a category, but these pages have custom URLs. My question is... how do I get Wordpress to show these links (the one pointing to the customized category pages) instead of the standard /category/ ones. Basically I want to tell Wordpress the custom link that he needs to use for each category

P.S.
I don't just want to 301-redirect them as I'm also interested in showing the custom URL behind the link, not just to get the visitor to the page.

Thanks!

---

Solved it myself:
Step 1 Use a plugin like Decategorizer to remove the /category/ from each permalink
Step 2 Modify the slugs from the wordpress category panel in order to match the custom urls of the landing pages

Answer (score 0):

If you want custom permalinks to be default then you should change your category permalinks. If you want a custom page to be default then you should customize your category pages (you can do category-$slug.php files or you can open up custom pages from category.php)